# Why std::atomic<T> Template don't provide sub_fetch() member function?

Tags: c++, atomic, compare-and-swap

[image]

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

std::atomic member function can only get the value before modification,
but I want to know how to get the value after modification in a atomic way

and why std::atomic Template don't provide those function like sub_fetch()?

Comment: You can easily get such a value by `a.fetch_sub(b)-b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does. It's called `operator-=`.

```
std::atomic<int> i(5);
int f = i -= 5;
std::cout << f << "\n"; // 0
```

`-=` is the way you would write this operation for a non-atomic object, so `std::atomic` uses the same operator. The `fetch_*` operations are the breaks from the norm because normal values don't have these operations, but atomic ones do. Because there is no available operator for them, they have to have alphabetic names.

Comment: Note that a problem with operators on atomics is that you cannot specify the memory ordering constratints.

Comment: operator -=  Equivalent to `fetch_add(arg)` - arg. Is the whole process is atomics?

Comment: @h-j-13 Yes, that expression is manifestly atomic. It also says so on the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith2#:~:text=Atomically).

Comment: Yeah, "it does" is kind of misleading when you can't specify the memory ordering. It half-does, at best.